# Change length(width) of sloping object in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

How I can change a length(width) of sloping object in illustrator? For example, there is an image which tell about my problem
[image]

How can I change more fast (and more correctly) positions of points from red circles to green circles?

I know a one approach when I make a path on the part of shape. Then I convert it to guide and then change positions of points, but with this approach I can't control a slope between this points. But I think this approach is very difficult and there is more simple approach.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

here's one way,

1. Ctrl+C, Ctrl+F, to make a copy of the shape
2. Grab the Rotate Tool (R), click on anchor A to set rotation point, then drag to rotate the segment to a horizontal position.

[image]

3. click on segment B, and Shift drag to the right, or tap on the Right Arrow to extend the segment to the desired length

[image]

4. grab the Rotate Tool (R) again, click and Anchor A to set rotation point, then drag Anchor C and drop it on top of Anchor D

[image]

5. remove original shape, or send copy to back to use it as guide to drag original shape's anchors onto it.

[image]

Comment: You can dispense the copy once you rotate illustrator will remember the angle just alt click and type minus in front.

Answer (score 1):

without drawing a path and convert it into guide you can use a guide line directly, by dragging a a a guide line from the ruler and rotate it to the extended direction and then snap your point over the guide line.

[image]

Comment: I think this way is not exactly and more difficult, because when I rotate a guide I can change a slope of path, because guide line dont snap to points

Comment: Never!!!. If you snap to points you will never miss it. I think you didn't give it a try.

Comment: Maybe something I do not understand. Can you demonstrate a little videodemo, please?

Answer (score 0):

Were you having a problem when you are trying to move the points one at a time? Try selecting both points before you move them. Or you can select the path in between the points and move it.

Comment: This way is not correct, because when I am dragging a path between the points I can change an angle of slope. This way suitable only approximately.